# Simplify a summation in the solution of $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-cx}x^{n}\arctan(ax)\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals, summation

### Context

I calculated this integral:
$$\begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-cx}x^{n}\arctan(ax)\mathrm{d}x=\\
\displaystyle\frac{n!}{c^{n+1}}\left\lbrace\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left[\text{Ci}\left(b\right)\sin\left(b-\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\text{Si}\left(b\right)\right)\cos\left(b-\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)\right]\frac{b^{k}}{k!}\right.\\
\displaystyle\left.\quad\qquad+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}\sum_{l=0}^{n-k}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi\left(l-j\right)}{2}\right)}{\left(j-1\right)!l!}b^{j+l-1}\right\rbrace\end{array}$$
Where:

- $b:=\dfrac{c}{a}$
- $\text{Si}(z)$ is the sine integral function
- $\text{Ci}(z)$ is the cosine integral function

### Question

I need help simplifying the last two summations:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{k}\sum_{l=0}^{n-k}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi\left(l-j\right)}{2}\right)}{\left(j-1\right)!l!}b^{j+l-1}$$

I can't find the transformation that allows me to calculate the sum only on the even "$l-j$" given that:
$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi\left(l-j\right)}{2}\right)=\begin{cases}(-1)^{l-j}&\text{if }l-j\text{ is even}\\
0&\text{if }l-j\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$

---

**My idea**
I noticed that the polynomial is odd, so technically it is possible to substitute $l-j=2s$ where $1\leq s\leq \left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: If you visualize the entries of the $l,j$ summation in a $n-k+1\times k$ array, all of the terms in the square of size $\min(n-k+1,k)$ cancel due to odd symmetry. This only leaves you with the largest terms in the summation, in the rectangular strip leftover (if there is one).

Comment: You might explore writing the $1/j!l!$ term as ${j+l\choose j}/(j+l)!$, the sine term in terms of exponentials, and introduce the change of variable $m = j+l$.

Comment: @Aruralreader I was thinking this sums as a sort a double integral above a triangular domain

Comment: For whatever it's worth, *Mathematica* gives the integral as $\frac{2^{n-1} \text{sgn}(a) G_{2,4}^{4,1}\left(\frac{c^2}{4 a^2}|\begin{array}{c} \frac{1}{2},1 \\ 0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{n+1}{2},\frac{n+2}{2} \\\end{array}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } c^{n+1}}$ where $G$ is the Meijer G function.

Comment: The most inner sum is already a monster : beside a bunch of floor function appear four  generalized hypergeometric functions

Comment: @JimB the definition of the Mejer $G$ it's too complex for me and the programs I use. I prefer to limit myself to the fact that $n$ is an integer (because I guess in this formulation you have given $n$ as a real number). *Mathematica* what does it say about summations?

Comment: There are Meijer G functions available that are stable and adequate if the objective is to obtain numerical values of the integral.  As far as the "last summation", if you specify $n$, then there is a great deal of simplification.  For $n=10$ that summation reduces to $\frac{b^9}{3628800}-\frac{17 b^7}{604800}+\frac{251 b^5}{151200}-\frac{119 b^3}{2160}+\frac{9 b}{10}$.